# Grails Bypass beforeUpdate Method of a Domain class

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I'm just curious if there is a way to bypass the `beforeUpdate()` and similar methods of a certain domain class.

I need it for restoring the original password of a user. The `beforeUpdate` proceeds the password hashing algorithm which I wouldn't like to call twice.

The only solution I could come up with is to use direct connection to the database and therefore bypass the `Hibernate`. This I don't like much cause of DB vendor lock-in etc.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you put a ishashed property on the domain....

You put it to false when you set the new password

In the beforeUpdate you test ishashed

if false you hash the password and set ishashed to true

Comment: I was thinking about this solution before but found some problems. But actually there are no - quite straight forward solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use HQL:

```
User.executeUpdate("update User u set u.password = :password where u.id = :userId",
    [password: oldHashedPassword, userId: userId])
```

This still uses Hibernate and its abstraction from your datasource vendor.